# How many characters has Warwick Davis played in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, actors

Warwick Davis is renowned as an actor that has appeared in a number of Star Wars media. He has appeared in multiple roles throughout the years including:

- A Ewok in ROTJ
- A side character in The Phantom Menance
- A rebel/pirate in Solo

**Are there any additional roles that Warwick Davis has acted in, in Star Wars?**

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Warwick_Davis

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be resolved by trivial research on a site [dedicated](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001116/) to telling you what films people stared in.

Comment: @Jontia That's a reason to downvote, not a reason to close. Trivia is not off topic here like it is on [movies.se].

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot should it be off topic for asking for a list of works then? As defined in the [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Jontia No, it's a small list so it isn't too broad and isn't asking for recommendations either. The question is perfectly on topic.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ok then. I've just noticed that the "Facts easily found on a reference site: Who played X in Y?" is no longer on the help centre page as well so I guess I'll rescind the close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He’s played many characters in *Star Wars*:

- he played Wicket in *Return of the Jedi* and the two Ewok TV movies
- in *The Phantom Menace*, he played:

  - Wald, a Rodian and Anakin’s friend
  - Yoda walking, sometimes
  - Weazel, a weapons dealer and a gambler at the podrace
  - a Tatooine street trader
- in *The Force Awakens*:

  - Wollivan
- in *The Last Jedi*:

  - Wodibin
  - Kedpin Shoplop
- in *Rebels*:

  - Thrawn's bodyguard, Ruhk (season 4)
- in *Rogue One*:

  - Weeteef Cyu-Bee (without hyphen on Wikipedia), a Talpini
- in *Solo*:

  - Weazel (again)
  - DD-BD
  - two other droids
  - “a hamster-like alien”
  - a rebel astronaut

Sources: [Warwick Davis on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warwick_Davis), [entertainment.ie](https://entertainment.ie/cinema/movie-news/warwick-davis-characters-harry-potter-star-wars-388754/), [Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-solo-warwick-davis-characters/)

Comment: "a hamster-like alien"? Do you have a source for that? (I'm just curious what it looked like.)

Comment: @Boolean In the Screen Rant article: “I was also watching the Sabacc game as that hamster-like alien character - it's a bit like a chinchilla, actually.”